# Using RestSharp formatters with Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, restsharp

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970660/1102726) on a stack overflow question suggests using a RestSharp XML serializer to serialize data to XML going out from ASP.NET Web API:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter = //RestSharp XML serializer here
```

What should be on the right-hand side of that expression?

I've also tried `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SetSerializer`, but 1) it requires a generic parameter, and I want it to work for everything, and 2) it cannot convert from 'RestSharp.Serializers.XmlSerializer' to 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer'.

I'm trying to serialize to XML an object that has an IList as a parameter, and I understand that XML serializer that comes with ASP.NET cannot process this, so I figured I'd try the RestSharp serializer.

***edit:***

My class I want to serialize looks something like this:

```
        public class Bar
        {
        }

        public class Foo
        {
            public virtual IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share how your type looks like?

Comment: @Kiran Challa: Sorry for the wait.  I've posted an example.